# Clean install Win10 on ext. HDD, sys image to internal HDD

Tags: clean-install

Did upgrade to Win10 but want to do clean install. I need the pc going so I want to clean install on an external hdd and then install all programs and settings. Once all that is good, can I do a system image of the external hdd and restore onto internal? I would have swapped out drives back and forth but internal is an msata. Thank you

Comment: If you want to do a clean install just use the Reset feature and choose "keep nothing" this will be much easier for you.  What you want to do is while not complicated is technically challenging